# How to generate thrift client with retry_overrides set?

Tags: python, thrift

I am using Apache Thrift to generate Python client code. In order to set `retry_overrides` I have to edit the generated class every time the client is regenerated.

Is it possible to set up `Thrift` so that it generate client with setup items I provide?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but it might be worth asking this question on the mailing list.

I also found two implementations of an [AbstractThriftClient](http://rubydoc.info/github/fauna/thrift_client/AbstractThriftClient), which might be what you are looking for. However, I don't know much about Python, so bear with me if I'm on the wrong path.